# How to Enable SSL Certificate for my website?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am new here. 

My website is [LifelineFoundations](http://lifelinefoundations.win/) and I haven't enabled SSL for this website.
Would someone please help me out and tell me the information regarding how to enable SSL certificate for my website, and in case if I won't enable it what would be the penalties I have to face?

Answer (score 1):

An SSL certificate works to create an encrypted connection between your visitor’s browser and the server.

To enable SSL Certificate for your Website follow below steps :

1. Host with a dedicated IP address
2. Buy a certificate
3. Activate the certificate
4. Install the certificate
5. Update your site to use HTTPS

If you have hosted you site with some Domain Providers like GoDaddy, they provide a [detailed list](https://in.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623) of instructions for installing SSL.
However if you have your own dedicated host with a web server installed, you need to generate CSR depending upon the operating system and have to make entry in the web servers. The instructions for the various web servers and operating system is mentioned [here](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation.htm) by DigiCert.

Regarding the impact if we don't go for SSL Certificate :

- Mostly all the web browsers mark your website as not secure which creates a bad impact when a visitor is browsing your website
- All the password and credentials would not be secure if entered through a non HTTPS Channel
- All the form data and sensitive information would be critical and vulnerable if you are not using TLS( connection used when SSL certificate is installed ).